# Website layout broken, possibly due to htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess, web-hosting

I recently had to migrate a site to a new host and copied the database and files over with no issues.

Now when I load the website all the media, css and links are broken, but I know the files are there.  I think I may have an issue with the htaccess file.

Here's the content of the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
#RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^files/.*$ - [PT]

RewriteRule ^(.*(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|txt|swf|php)+)$ - [PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !admin

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?section=$1 [L,QSA]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

the website is francokickboxing.com.  I'm not the original developer of this website, and I was just asked by a friend when they decided to move their hosting.

Comment: I don't know the answer but why don't you try commenting everything and re-enable line per line?

Comment: move your RewriteCond lines (the last 2) up to before the RewriteRules

Comment: I will give the rewriteCond lines a check, right now the host is spouting a 'If you see this page, it means that your domain is not setup with physical hosting or doesnt have a www record set.'

I recently moved this about 30 hours ago to it's new host.  Could the DNS still be refreshing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `L` flags to your rules and make sure the conditions at the end actually get applied to the index route:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^files/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|txt|swf|php)+)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?section=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If they're still broken, then you may have a relative URL issue. If you have relative links for all your css/scripts/media, then you either need to change them to absolute urls (starts with `/`) or add a relative URI base to your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Broken relative url issue in the include file.  changed the url to '/' instead of the domain and everything fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

move your RewriteCond lines (the last 2) up to before the RewriteRules

Since they are basically your logic (if checks) you are never getting there... the if check needs to come before the execution of the rule:)